# DataMapper can't delete record because of relation

Tags: mysql, ruby, orm, relational-database, datamapper

I have this many-many DataMapper/MySQL setup with Torrent and Tag, as follows:

```
class Torrent
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,          Serial
  property :name,        String
  property :magnet,      Text
  property :created_at,  DateTime

  has n, :tags, :through => Resource
end

class Tag
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,      Serial
  property :name,    String
  property :hits,    Integer

  has n, :torrents, :through => Resource
end
```

When trying to destroy a torrent, however, via `Torrent.first.destroy` or something similar, DataMapper returns `false`.

I tried straight SQL queries like `delete from torrents where name like '%ubuntu%'`, which failed because of MySQL error 1451:

```
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`brightswipe`.`tag_torrents`, CONSTRAINT `tag_torrents_torrent_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`torrent_id`) REFERENCES `torrents` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I figure there's some DataMapper setup whereby when deleting a torrent I can:

1. Remove the tag associations
2. Delete the torrent

And when deleting a tag I can:

1. Remove the tag association from all torrents with that tag
2. Delete the tag

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using this plugin to have relations managed automatically:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-constraints

This will allow you to destroy M:M assocs though you'll have to cleanup the assocs table manually:

```
class Tag
  ...
  has n, :torrents, :through => Resource, :constraint => :skip

class Torrent
  ...
  has n, :tags, :through => Resource, :constraint => :skip
```

**Another option** is to remove the relation from assocs table manually, then you'll can remove items without any issues, cause you destroyed the relation by removing corresponding entry from assocs table.

basic example:

```
tr = Torrent.create
tg = Tag.create

tr.tags << tg
tr.save

tg.torrents << tr
tg.save

# destroying relation

TagTorrent.first(:tag => tg, :torrent => tr).destroy!

# or
tr.tag_torrents(:tag => tg).destroy

# or
tg.tag_torrents(:torrent => tr).destroy

# destroy items

tr.destroy!
tg.destroy!
```

Comment: Will that remove the tag associations upon deletion of torrents? And drop tag associations upon tag deletions?

Comment: Also, the "constraint=>set_nil" thing raises an ArgumentError; it's invalid for a ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: please try `:constraint => :skip` then

Comment: @silvu please explain what that does.

Comment: @silvu - and that will remove relationships instead of deleting the other? i'd rather that when tags get deleted, they get removed from the association table, and vice versa when torrents get deleted

Comment: this will make `dm` to not raise error and entry remove to succeed. you'll have to cleanup your assoc table manually

Comment: except for the fact that I don't even manage my assoc table manually. that's handled through the `has n` - so how do i handle that automatically?

Comment: see the second link above. basically you can access it by `TagTorrent` model or by `torrent_obj.tag_torrents` or `tag_obj.tag_torrents`

Comment: I have not made a TagTorrent model, so I guess that is in order. thanks. so i delete the tag_torrents then delete the obj?

Comment: `TagTorrent` model are created automatically by `dm` and you can use as usual model. updated the answer. also see how it works [**here**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=datamapper-cant-delete-record-because-of-relation_without_plugin.rb&run=true)