# Strange DataMapper Issue

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have a associative model, when I try to delete a record it returns `true` but the  record still exists,
 The Model has 2 columns which are `keys`, while the third column is an `enum`, also a key.
Any tips relating to updating/deleting a associative model in DataMapper

```
class A
   #some property definition
end

class B
   #some property definition
end

class C
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include DataMapper::Grape::Resource

  expose :type

  property :type, Enum[:a, :b], :key => true, :unique => false

  belongs_to :a, :key => true
  belongs_to :b, :key => true

end
```

**Inside racksh**

```
element = C.get(:a,1,1)
# => returns Hash Object
# Fine till now
element.destroyed?
# => true
# I dont know why did it return true, I am 100% sure I havent performed destroy or destroy! on element
element.type
# => :a
element.type = :b
# => DataMapper::ImmutableError: Immutable resource cannot be modified
element.destroy!
# => true
C.get(:a,1,1)
# => the same Hash Object rather than returning nil
```

Comment: Can u write the relationship between the tables and the queries used..

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144198

Comment: I get DataMapper::Immutable issue when tried to update the record, I went through the stackoverflow but none answered my concern, will post the relationships soon

Comment: @GhostRider I have added the code for the models & what did I try till now

Comment: @GhostRider I have added the code for the models & what did I try till now